# jsp page showing only one word of the string

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

I am displaying database values from DAO class to servlet and then with setAttribute displaying it over a jsp page. Now if the database value has a two word string then only the first word is getting displayed over jsp page's text field. I tried to check that whether at every point the brand value is same or not and with sysout saw that even upto jsp page its showing two words (like Peter England). Also with ctrl+u in the browser saw that in the value of brand tag only "Peter" is showing as value and "England" is showing like a attribute with different colour than "Peter".

```
<label>Brand *</label>
<input type="text" name="brand" value=Peter England>
```

Here's my code snippet, so kindly tell me what's am doing wrong here, banging my head for this for past two days ...

I have a bean class named AddInventoryBean.

```
AddInventoryBean dataList=new CheckInventoryDAO().checkInventory(addinvbean);
request.setAttribute("brand", dataList.getPRODUCT_MODEL_BRAND());
request.getRequestDispatcher("/show.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Now in jsp page:

```
 <label>Brand *</label>
 <input type="text" name="brand" value=<%=request.getAttribute("brand") %>>
```

Comment: You need quotes around your value : value="Peter England". Also, close your input tag with a slash: <input ... />

Comment: As @user1884155 mentions, you need quotes around your accessor: `value='<%=request.getAttribute("brand") %>` />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for the above problem is simple just start with double inverted comma before JSP tag.

In your case

```
value="<%=request.getAttribute("brand")%>"
```

so that the HTML takes the brand name with spaces as one value.